# Какой прокси выбрать

Tags: парсер, proxy

Есть парсер, на python scrapy. Парсит все товары с магазина. Все работает, все ништяк, парситься каждая страница, НО медленно. Каждый товар парсился примерно 3-4 секунды (там переходит на страницу товара). Пробовал быстрее - упирается в лимиты и выводит ошибку. Поигрался с настройками, ускорил до примерно 1 - 2 секунды / продукт. И то это много чтобы распарсить целый магазин. Погуглив понял, что нужно использовать proxy чтобы сайт не забанил.
Так вот собественно вопросы, какой тип парсера нужен? Сколько нужно proxy (почти не нашел информации)? Какой сервис посоветуете? ...
Где можно об этом всем почитать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Парсер должен уметь работать через прокси, должен уметь использовать прокси с авторизацией, и должен уметь работать многопоточно (т.к. именно в этом смысл использования прокси).

Сколько нужно прокси - это только вы можете знать.

Представим сферическую ситуацию в вакууме: нужно спарсить магазин из 10 000 товаров. Каждый товар парсится ~3 сек + 1 сек на разные непредвиденные расходы, итого 4 сек. 10 000 товаров х 4 сек = 40 000 сек. Т.е. в идеальной ситуации в один поток вы спасите магазин за 11+ часов непрерывного парсинга.

Представим что мы купили 5 прокси и будем парсить через них (через свой ip не будем, только через прокси). Значит в идеальной ситуации мы спарсим в 5 раз быстрее - за 2+ часа.

Не стоит думать что если купишь 100 прокси то спарсишь в 100 раз быстрее - ресурсы сервера не безграничны и вы можете уложить сайт, либо он будет очень медленно отвечать, либо админы заметят повышенную нагрузку и забанят ip адреса ваших прокси.

Где покупать прокси - не буду никого рекламировать. В инете полно вариантов по этому запросу. Не кидайтесь на первые попавшиеся рекомендации или хорошие отзывы, часто цена у них завышена 200-300р шт/мес. Я находил по 50р шт/мес и они работали нормально (но так везёт не всегда).

Я для парсинга использовал обычные HTTP/HTTPS прокси. Можно и SOCKS если парсер их поддерживает.

Важно понимать, что кроме протокола (HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS и др) у прокси есть и другие важные характеристики:

1. Страна - некоторые сайты не будут открываться из некоторых стран. Потому если ваша страна условно РФ, то надежнее покупать прокси РФ. Либо проверять открывается ли сайт из страны в которой прокси.
2. Ipv4 и Ipv6 - первые дороже но работают со всеми сайтами, вторые дешевле но нужно проверять работает ли ваш сайт через Ipv6 прокси.
3. Бывают прокси "Shared"/"Общие" и "В одни руки"/"Индивидуальные". Как несложно догадаться - общие прокси дешевле, но кроме вас их использует еще кто-то (обычно до 3-х чел у нормальных сервисов). Т.е. насколько они будут загружены зависит от ваших "соседей" (как повезет). Индивидуальные продаются только вам и соответственно вам доступны все ресурсы.